# Find shortcuts on OS X

Tags: macos, macos-bigsur

I'm trying to set a global shortcut for a deamon but OS X Big Sur seems to already use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for something else.

I've looked though Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and those two shortcuts are not bound to anything right now. But when I press them I hear a sound indicating that the computer is trying to do something but failed, ie. they are still bound to something.

My question: is there some "shortcut explorer" or something in OS X (Big Sur) where I can press a shortcut and see what it's bound to?

Comment: Finder uses them for Go to - Network or Folder. Other Apps use them for other things. If it beeps, then nothing is assigned, but globally overriding something with different purposes in different apps is going to be … fun. Possible but irritating to set up. I'd pick another shortcut. [Cheatsheet](https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/) will show you commands per app, but not global.

Comment: +1 for this, for a global tool.  Something has stolen my F11 key, so I can't use for normal Finder/Dashboard/Notifications stuff like I used to.  Those keystrokes don't show up when running Cheatsheet in the Finder, although thanks for that tip, Tetsujin.